# top and bottom positioning with auto?

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, css, xhtml

My outer div is position:relative and inner div is positioned absolute.

I want to set my inner div center align vertically and thinking to use top:auto and bottom:auto but it is not working. Please advice me how it can be done.

```
        div.Container div.Right 
    {
            width:50%;
            float:right ;
            border: 01px dashed green;
            height:95px !important;    
            position:relative !important;
    }   

     div.header-search
    {    
        overflow:auto;
        display:inline;    
        border:0px dashed blue;        
        position:absolute;
        top:auto;
        bottom:auto;
        right:0px;
    }



 <div class="Right">
            <div class="header-search">
                <input type="text" class="searchbox" />
                <input type="button" class="searchbutton" value="›" />
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `line-height:95px;` in the outer div and `vertical-align: middle;` in the inner div like this:

```
div.Right
{
    width:50%;
    float:right ;
    border: 01px dashed green;
    line-height:95px !important;   
    display: block;
}   

div.header-search
{    
    overflow:auto;
    border:0px dashed blue;       
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/5Mm67/

---

If you want to horizontal align the content of the inner div, just add this in `div.Right`:

`text-align: center;`

Here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/5Mm67/1/

Answer (score 0):

the best way to achieve what you are after would be to remove the `bottom:auto;` style and replace the `top:auto;` with `top:50%;` . After that work out the height of the search bar that you are trying to center (say its 20px) and add a negative margin styles for half of its height, so if it was 20px the style would be `margin-top:-10px;`

your css would look like this:

```
 div.header-search
{    
    overflow:auto;
    display:inline;    
    border:0px dashed blue;        
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
height:20px;
margin-top:-10px;
right:0;

}​
```

Answer (score 0):

set .header-search to top:50% or bottom:50% then use margin-top:-(half of div height) or margin-bottom:-(half of div height); respectively. I also sometimes just simply use top:50% or bottom: 50% without the negative margins.

For example:

```
 div.header-search
    {    
        overflow:auto;
        display:inline;    
        border:0px dashed blue;        
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        height: 500px;
        margin-top:-250px;
        right:0px;
    }
```

So yeah, in this case you would have to set a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

Set in the div with position absolute: "top:50%;"

It will display the div a litle bit to low (top od the absolute div should be exacly on the 50% of parent height - relative div) but there are ways to go around this.

For example:
Do even one more div with position relative and move it higher with half of absolute div height (this doesnt look very nice in code) - You must know the divs height, if you dont you can measure the size in sth like jQuery and move div a litle higher.

Easiest way: Maybe try 45% instead of 50% (if its not pixel to pixel design).

Propably somebody has better solutions, if so I would like to see them to :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
div.header-search
{    
    overflow:auto;
    display:inline;    
    border:0px dashed blue;        
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hie, there are several methods to vertical centering of div its done through the magic of CSS.... Here is the examples and it works fine i have tested... and it works fine.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {position: relative;}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: -15% 0 0 -25%;
}
```

Here is other methods [click here to see complete reference](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/)
Hope, it will helps you. Cheers. !!

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the inner div to margin: auto 0;

Comment: this works for horizontally centering elements with a fixed width, but not for vertically centering stuff